# set left margin for view ... NullPointerException is coming

Tags: android, android-layout

my code This is an adapter and I want to align my layout dynamically to left and right in a list view...And null pointer exception is coming at `relativeParams.leftMargin=80;`

Java:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        ChatItem chatItem = getItem(position);
        viewAligned = view;
        if(view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)  
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_messages_layout, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fromZoneMessage1);
            viewHolder.rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.messageLayout);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.message.setText(chatItem.getSenderMessage());
        if (chatItem.getAllignment() == 0)
        {
//          viewHolder.message.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            viewHolder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sent_message);
//          view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sent_message);
        }
        else {
//          viewHolder.rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recieved_message);
//          view.holder.rl.set
//          viewHolder.message.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            viewHolder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recieved_message);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) viewHolder.rl.getLayoutParams();
            relativeParams.leftMargin=80;
            viewHolder.rl.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
//          LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        }
        return view;
    }
```

**And my Layout is....**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/messageLayout" 
   >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/fromZoneMessage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Hey Jack"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please somebody help me to put left margin for my view....

Comment: Put `view.setTag(viewHolder);` before `return view;`

Comment: In provided layout i am not able to locate `R.id.messageLayout` id for `RelativeLayout`. are you sure using right layout for ListView row view ?

Comment: view.setTag(viewHolder) is not working...but thanks

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure Its relative layout for listView's row... is there any other way

Comment: You `RelativeLayout` does not contain `id` attribute in XML.

Comment: See the edited Question please..I forgot to provide you the latest one ... sorry...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025872/using-relativelayout-dynamically-and-setting-margins-in-px-dp-inch-mm

Comment: Hey see the Fix I made in my answer...@codePG,  ツ Fell in Love with Android ツ,    ρяσѕρєя K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just type casted the view to Relative Layout and set its Gravity...For setting the parameters , means Margins I've taken another dummy Relative Layout inside of Main Relative layout and Adjusted it.

You can watch the below code and Relative layout

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        ChatItem chatItem = getItem(position);
        viewAligned = view;
        if(view == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cell_messages_layout, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fromZoneMessage1);
            viewHolder.rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.messageLayout);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.message.setText(chatItem.getSenderMessage());
        if (chatItem.getAllignment() == 0)
        {

            viewHolder.message.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            viewHolder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.recieved_message);
            ((RelativeLayout)view).setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.leftMargin = 50;
            viewHolder.rl.setLayoutParams(params);

                    }
        else {
            viewHolder.message.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            viewHolder.message.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sent_message);
            ((RelativeLayout)view).setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.rightMargin = 50;
            viewHolder.rl.setLayoutParams(params);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/messageLayout" 
       >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/fromZoneMessage1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Hey Jack"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using RelativeLayout.LayoutParams try to use AbsListView.LayoutParams as your view is in ListView.

Comment: Not Working  @Yogesh Narayanan

Comment: Yeah  @Yogesh Narayanan

Comment: I think you can create new instance of layoutparams (do not use getLayoutParams() of rl) and set necessary alignments and assign it to rl.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: Yeah After a lot of Struggle I fixed it ... You can see the below answer by me...@Yogesh Narayanan